# How to add group, or page field in an existing .rdl report

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, rdl

I have several .rdl reports designed for our client. However, they need new ones, that are relatively similar to the old ones. Differences are in the "group" and "page fields" (these can be changed easily). I'm interested in adding new group and page fields.

I would like to copy/paste the old report, and then add new (group and page) fields, without creating new report from wizard (so I don't need to copy design, nor queries). Is there a way?

Comment: I also need drilldown enabled on new group fields, and disabled on the old ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i've got just the blog for you!

go to the table properties, go to groups, and click add.

to enable drill down, go to the table properts, go to groups, click a group and click edit, and go to visibility.  set your initial visibility and click the check box and select a cell textbox that will toggle the group.

[creating basic drilldowns](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/creating-a-basic-drilldown-report-in-ssr-2005)

Comment: @smhnkmr the site's experiencing some difficulties atm

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found to do this is to make a copy in windows explored and rename it. Then add the renamed report to a project and delete anything you don't need.

Comment: You've missed the poing a little bit. I have copied report, added new fields, erased unnecessary ones... The main problem is how to make new fields "group fields" (and enable/disable drilldown), and "page fields"